# Sort 2D Array in PHP

Tags: php, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(

[90] => Array
    (
        [1056] => 44.91
        [1055] => 53.56
        [1054] => 108.88
        [1053] => 23.28

    ), 
[63] => Array
    (
        [1056] => 44.44
        [1055] => 53.16
        [1054] => 108.05

    ), 
[21] => Array
    (
        [1056] => 42.83
        [1055] => 51.36
        [1054] => 108.53
    )
);
```

Both keys ([x] and [y]) refer to IDs in my database, so those need to stay intact. The order of the [x] does not matter, but I need to sort each array by the value of [y].

**Edit:**
I have tried this loop, but it does not seem to work:

```
foreach($distance as $key=>$value) {
    asort($value,SORT_NUMERIC);
}
```

Comment: You could just loop through the outer array with a foreach and sort every inner array with ksort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`ksort`](http://php.net/ksort) (or [`uksort`](http://php.net/uksort)) to sort the arrays by their keys.

UPDATE: Use [`asort`](http://php.net/asort) (or [`uasort`](http://php.net/uasort)) to sort by values, preserving keys.

UPDATE 2: Try this

```
foreach($distance as &$value) {
    asort($value,SORT_NUMERIC);
}
```

Comment: I want to sort by the values (44.91, 53.96, etc), not the keys ([1055],[1056], etc).

Comment: Try the loop I added.  I think the problem was that asort changed the $value array, but since that wasn't by reference, it didn't save it back to the original array.

Answer (score 3):

Like this?

```
array_walk($array, 'asort');
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`asort()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) for sorting by values. It maintains the index associations.

For the loop, you need to pass `$value` by reference, so you need to use `&$value`.

Answer (score 0):

```
 array_multisort($arrindex1, SORT_DESC, $arrindex2, SORT_DESC, $array);
```